# VS2017, xamarin shows lots of errors befor i even start to code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I just installed Visual Studio 2017 and tried to make a cross plattform app with xamarin forms. But when i load in it just shows over 100 errors before i even started to code.

here is a list of errors:

PS: dont care about the name just something random, that came to my mind.

here is a link to the errorlist:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ixABU2Oydk0gWwyGELjdQPiKdDygs4d9PqwkfIo-1MU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try building and allowing the nuget packages to restore, you might also be missing an android sdk.